# How do I build a new raster based on raster stats in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, rasterstats

I want to create a new raster that uses the mean value of the original raster as the base class of the image and then uses a +- 1 and 2 standard deviations as the other four classes of the image.  Is there a simple way to do this in QGIS?

Here is the equation I used before posting my question. What am I doing wrong? 2018712@5 is the band I'm working with. 194.26 and 9.8663 are the mean and standard deviation respectively.

```
("2018712@5" >= (194.26+(9.8663*1)))*1 + ("2018712@5" >= (194.26+(9.8663*1.5)))*1.5 + ("2018712@5" >= (194.26+(9.8663*2)))*2 + ("2018712@5" <= (194.26+(9.8663*-1)))*-1 + ("2018712@5" <= (194.26+(9.8663*-1.5)))*-1.5 + ("2018712@5" <= (194.26+(9.8663*-2)))*-2
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using version 2.18 and updated to 3.4.5.  Updating to the new version fixed my problem.